# Declaring integer values in MIPS

Tags: mips

So I am writing an assembly program that has lots of constant integer values.

I know that in the .data section I can assign a label with a .word data type and type in my number. With this method I still have to load an address in main.

But in main, I could just simply use

*li $t1, some_number*

Are any one of these methods better than the other and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I'd say using `li` is the better approach. You're avoiding adding a bunch of clutter in your `.data` section, and you will also get more efficient code in some cases.

Let's look at some examples:

```
.data
ten: .word 10
million: .word 1000000

.text 
main:
    lw $t0,ten
    li $t1,10
    lw $t2,million
    li $t3,1000000
```

It's important to understand here that both `lw` and `li` are *pseudo-instructions* that get translated into one or more actual instructions. `lw` *does* exist in the MIPS instruction set, but this particular variant of it doesn't. `li` doesn't exist in the MIPS instruction set.

If we look at what SPIM generates for the first two instructions, we see:

```
[0x00400024]    0x3c011001  lui $1, 4097                    ; 9: lw $t0,ten
[0x00400028]    0x8c280000  lw $8, 0($1)

[0x0040002c]    0x3409000a  ori $9, $0, 10                  ; 10: li $t1,10
```

So that's one additional instruction for the `lw` variant, as the address first has to be loaded into a register, and then the value is loaded from that address. This also means one additional (potentially slow) memory access (well, two if you count the instruction fetch).

Now let's look at the other two instructions, where the value to be loaded is too large to be encoded in a single instruction:

```
[0x00400030]    0x3c011001  lui $1, 4097                    ; 11: lw $t2,million
[0x00400034]    0x8c2a0004  lw $10, 4($1)

[0x00400038]    0x3c01000f  lui $1, 15                      ; 12: li $t3,1000000
[0x0040003c]    0x342b4240  ori $11, $1, 16960
```

Here the immediate 1000000 is loaded using two instructions as `(15 << 16) | 16960`. So both variants require two instructions, but the `li` variant doesn't need to read from memory.

---

If you want to assign a meaningful name to a constant to avoid having magic numbers all over your code you can do so with `=`:

```
TEN = 10

li $t0, TEN   # Expands to li $t0, 10
```

---

<sup><sub>You could perhaps avoid loading the addresses for `lw` all the time by using `$gp`-relative addressing, but I feel that that's beyond the scope of this question.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks for that extensive reply!