# Example usage of $at register in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

My textbook says that the MIPS assembler must break large constants into pieces and then reassemble them into a register. And that it uses the $at as a temporary register for

I've been looking for a concrete example of this, does anyone have one?

I've seen some websites say that the `la` pseudo-instruction converts into instructions using `$at`, but that doesn't seem to be needed. For example:

```
la $t0, 0xABCD1234
```

converts into

```
lui $t0, 0xABCD
ori $t0, $t0, 0x1234
```

Comment: Try reading this: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/load32.html ... it's been about 15 years since I've used MIPS

Comment: You don't need `$at` to assemble 32-bit constants in general. You may need it to do branches when the native `beq/bgez/bgtz/blez/bltz` aren't enough and you need to `slt*` to build a different predicate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the link is no longer working, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example taken from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32434261/1524450) to an earlier question regarding the use of `li` and `lw`:

Given the following code:

```
.data
ten: .word 10

.text 
main:
    lw $t0, ten
```

SPIM would generate the following instruction sequence for the `lw`:

```
0x3c011001  lui $1, 4097                    ; lw $t0,ten
0x8c280000  lw $8, 0($1)
```

The address of `ten` is first placed in `$1` (`$at`), and then the value is loaded from that address.

Perhaps `sw` would be a better example. In the case of `lw` I suppose you could've expanded the `lw` into `lui $8, 4097 / lw $8, ($8)`. But in the case of `sw` you wouldn't want to overwrite `$t0` with the address.